# Why is the return type of GetGlobalResourceObject and GetLocalResourceObject methods 'object' and not 'string'?

Tags: asp.net, globalization, resx

According to [How to: Create Resource Files for ASP.NET Web Sites](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246.aspx),

> A resource file is an XML file that can contain strings and other resources, such as image file paths.

Also from the same article,

> Do not attempt to embed a graphic directly in a resource file because controls will not read the resource string as a streamed image file. Resource files represent graphics by storing the URL of the graphic as a string.

So basically they always store `String` values (which may be file paths too). But from the documentation for [GetGlobalResourceObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.getglobalresourceobject(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GetLocalResourceObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.getlocalresourceobject(v=vs.110).aspx) methods, both have return type `System.Object`.

Why do they return `System.Object` which then must be cast into `String`?
Are there cases where these methods return something other than a String value?

Answer (score 0):

Because you can also store images and other things as resources.

Comment: But you can only store image "paths" right (As per the article in my question and the quote) ? Which are again strings.

Comment: You can store image path or whole images.But personally, I would not store images inside Resource files, it's hard to maintain. Paths are much easier.